# Recordset is not Updateable in Access Query

Tags: ms-access

I'm having this very annoying issue. I can't understand why my query is not editable. Please help. Here below is the query design.

[image]

Comment: See Allen Browne's [note on read-only queries](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html). But as I see this query should be updateable for ONLY the `tblLL87Extensions` fields. In fact all the others should update with values in `ContractID`. See if in datasheet view you see "New" in the asterisk row under this id field.

Comment: No. I do not see "New" or an asterisk. Thanks for the helpful reply. But can you explain to me how it isn't updateable? I have another similar query which is updateable. The only difference between these two queries is that the equivalent tblLL87Extensions table in that query has unique ContractID values. Isn't there a way I can have extensions with multiple contractIDs as well as have the query to be updateable?

Comment: Try this. Begin with `tblLL87Extensions` then add subsequent tables one by one and see at which point you lose the updateable ability (i.e., no longer see "New"). It could be some condition of a table, possibly lookup fields/locked/not null, etc.

Comment: It only works with the LL87Extensions and LL87Status tables. The only difference between this query and other functioning queries in my database is that in this case, tblLL87Extensions has its ContractID set to "can have duplicates"